# "China's ambassador"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

If I see something like "China's ambassador" or "China ambassador" with no further clues, does it mean an ambassador *to* that country or *that country's* ambassador? Or could it mean both and there's no way to figure it out without further context? I haven't included it on purpose, because my question is not simply about what some sentence I came across mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"China's ambassador" or "the Chinese ambassador" always mean "The ambassador **from** China.

If you don't mean that, you need to say "The (American) ambassador *to* China".

I would not use "China ambassador" (but would assume it means the same as "Chinese ambassador")

Answer (score 1):

If  s/he works for China s/he would usually be referred to as "The Chinese ambassador" or "China's ambassador". "China's ambassador to [some country]" is often needed.

I can't imagine a sentence such as you describe, having "China ambassador" **with no further clues**, though informally perhaps "Here comes **our** China Ambassador" might be used if s/he is from '*here*'.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=China%20ambassador%2CChinese%20ambassador%2CChina%27s%20ambassador&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CChina%20ambassador%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CChinese%20ambassador%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CChina%20%27s%20ambassador%3B%2Cc0) illustrates the frequency of the usages.